# Adding row to a table causes dropdown function to duplicate

Tags: angularjs

I have created a table with a row that has three dropdowns

**Drug  - Dose  - Period**

I also created a button **Add Drug** that will add another row of the same dropdowns

I am getting the data from a database and populating it in the dropdown

**Exception**:

The dose dropdown changes depending on what the drug is. So I created a watcher to check when the `value` of the drug changes, and then created an array of the dose data called `$scope.array` and populated it in `$scope.selectedDose` which are the values inside the dose dropdown. So the first drug dose data is different than the second drug dose data. **Please select the second drug and 5th drug from dropdown in jsfiddle and see how dose values changes**

```
$scope.$watch("value",  function() {
  $scope.array = $scope.value.dose_array.split(',');
  $scope.selectedDose = $scope.array[0];
});
```

**Problem**:

If you play around with my JSFiddle link that I shared, you will find that when adding a drug with the button and selecting another drug from the first, the dose data of the first row changes too. The reason for that is because `$scope.selectedDose` is changing with any drug data from any row

The solution that I thought of is creating an array of an array

```
$scope.selectedDose[rowIndex] = $scope.array[0];
```

with every row added, the dose dropdown will have its own `selectedDose` data. However it was complicated and was not able to accomplish it

Any solutions for this problem ? I have added the JSFiddle and organized my code as much as possible. It should demonstrate my problem very well

**JSFIDDLE**

http://jsfiddle.net/jq3fxx72/3/

Comment: `TypeError: Cannot read property 'dose_array' of null` at `$scope.array = $scope.value.dose_array.split(',');`

Comment: Thats just the first error becuase there's no value selected for the first dropdown. @MikkoViitala

Comment: I think the problem is that instead of copying an inert object, your `addRow` function is copying the first element of the array (`$scope.rows[0]`).  Try creating an object you can clone from outside the array so that when you set the first row to a value, it doesn't cascade.

Comment: Could you elaborate by writing an answer ? There is already the object rows created. and if I replace ($scope.rows[0]) by ($scope.rows) it still copies the Dose array @Claies

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I wouldn't add a watch for adding the `doseArray`. You could add it to the `ng-click` event and add it to the current `row` as `doseArray`.

Also improve your variable & function names because no one knows what a function `func` does. Good names will help you to understand your code.

Please have a look at the demo below or in this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/awolf2904/jq3fxx72/5/).

```js
app = angular.module('app', []);
app.controller('myCtrl', ['$scope', '$http', function ($scope, $http) {
    $scope.rows = [];
    var rowTmpl = {
        'drug': "Drug",
        'dose': 'Dose',
        'period': "Period",
    };

    // init first row
    $scope.rows.push(angular.copy(rowTmpl));

    //PERIOD

    $scope.period = {
        currentPeriod: "1 day"
    };

    $scope.periods = [
        "1 day",
        "2 days",
        "3 days",
        "4 days"];

    $http.get('http://medicaladvisto.com/getDrugs').success(function (data) {
        $scope.ourDatas = data;
        //console.log(data);
    });

    $scope.setDose = function (row, drug) {
        //console.log('Selcted', drug);
        var index = $scope.ourDatas.indexOf(drug);
        if (index === -1) return;

        var doseArray = $scope.ourDatas[index].dose_array.split(',');
        row.doseOptions = doseArray;
    };

    //ADDING ROWS

    $scope.addRow = function () {
        var newRow = angular.copy(rowTmpl);
        newRow.selectedPeriod = null;
        newRow.singleSelect = null;
        $scope.rows.push(newRow);
    };

    $scope.removeRow = function (rowIndex) {
        if (confirm('Are you sure you want to delete this?')) $scope.rows.splice(rowIndex, 1);
    }
}]);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="myCtrl">
    <div class="buttons"> <a class="navbar-brand" ng-click="addRow()" href="#">
                    <button class="btn btn-default"> Add Drug</button></a> 
        <!-- adds rows -->
    </div>
    <table class="table">
        <tr ng-repeat="(rowIndex, row) in rows">
            <td>{{ourDatas.doseOptions}}</td>
            <td>
                <label for="singleSelect">{{row.drug}}
                    <select class="form-control" popover="Choose your input drug, type to filter list of drugs" data-ng-model="row.singleSelect" ng-click="setDose(row, row.singleSelect)" data-ng-options="name.dname for name in ourDatas" style="width:300px;" required></select>
                </label>
            </td>
            <td>
                <label for="selectedDose">{{row.dose}}
                    <select class="form-control" popover="Choose dosage amount" data-ng-model="row.selectedDose" ng-options='dose for dose in row.doseOptions' style="width:200px;" required></select>
                </label>
            </td>
            <td>
                <!-- Periods dropdown selection box -->
                <label>{{row.period}}
                    <select class="form-control" popover="Choose how many times a day taken" data-ng-model="row.selectedPeriod" data-ng-options="name for name in periods" style="width:100px;" required></select>
                </label>
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="button" value="-" class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="removeRow(rowIndex)" />
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

Comment: Than you very much good sir. I would like to know why adding a watch function is not a good idea ?

Comment: You're welcome. I think adding watches is OK if you really need them but they can slow down your app if you have many of them because they are checked pretty often by angular. So it's better to do something on user interaction (`ng-click` / `ng-change` ...) and try to avoid `$watch`. There is also a nice [post](http://www.alexkras.com/11-tips-to-improve-angularjs-performance/) about avoiding watches.